# Steps on how to decrypt XML using private key in a PFX keystore with Java

Tags: java, xml, encryption, pfx

We have a requirement to encrypt request payloads and decrypt responses that follows the [W3 standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core1/). I was to get the encryption following what was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261251/examples-or-tutorials-about-santuario-java).

Now what needs to be now is the decryption which I find not as straight forward like a reverse of the encryption. What I have searched so far discussed symmetric encryption and decryption and involving just some String values.

This is how the response looks (namespace URLs shortened):

```
<xenc:EncryptedData Type="xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="xmlenc#">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
    <dsig:KeyInfo xmlns:dsig="xmldsig#">
        <xenc:EncryptedKey Recipient="name:55bb96ec-...">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
            <dsig:KeyInfo>
                <dsig:KeyName>55bb96ec-....</dsig:KeyName>
            </dsig:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>nO6Hic8FxebFy.....</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedKey>
    </dsig:KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:CipherValue>j9v2IznqpwCunQiZG....</xenc:CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
```

Below is what I have so far which is encountering below error. The expectation is that the decrypted XML has the actual response structure with digital signature.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key size
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCrypt.init(DESedeCrypt.java:69)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherBlockChaining.init(CipherBlockChaining.java:93)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:591)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineInit(DESedeCipher.java:197)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:809)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:867)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1399)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1330)
    at testDecrypt.main(testDecrypt.java:90)
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


//import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;

public class testDecrypt {
    static {
        org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xmlInput = "ENCRYPTED XML FOLDER\XENC FILE.xml";
        String keyStorePW = "PFX password";
        String keyStore = "PFX FILE FOLDER\PFX File.pfx";
        
        //build document from input xml file
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(xmlInput);
        
        //load the Private Key from Keystore
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(keyStore), keyStorePW.toCharArray());
        String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, keyStorePW.toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Private Key: "+privKey);
        
        //Get the encrypted Key and data element from input xml
        NodeList cipherValueNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("xenc:CipherValue");
        Element encKey = null;
        Element encData = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < cipherValueNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                encKey = (Element)cipherValueNodes.item(i);
            }
            else {
                encData = (Element)cipherValueNodes.item(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Encrypted key: "+encKey.getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Encrypted data: "+encData.getTextContent());
        
        //Start decryption of encrypted Key using the private key
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
        byte[] encryptedKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encKey.getTextContent());
        byte[] decryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(encryptedKeyBytes);
        DESedeKeySpec desEdeKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(decryptedKey);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(desEdeKeySpec);
        System.out.println("Key size:"+key.getEncoded().length);
        
        //decrypt the encrypted data element using the secrek key
        int ivLen = 8;
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[ivLen];
        byte[] encryptedDataBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encData.getTextContent());
        System.arraycopy(encryptedDataBytes, 0, ivBytes, 0, ivLen);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        Cipher cipherData = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipherData.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivParameterSpec);
        String decryptedData = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedDataBytes, ivLen, encryptedDataBytes.length - ivLen));
        System.out.println("DEcrypted Data: "+decryptedData);
        
        //write the Decrypted XML
        File encryptionFile = new File("FILE OUTPUT DIRECTORY\decryptedInfo2.xml");
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(encryptionFile);
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(f);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        f.close();
        System.out.println(
            "Wrote document containing encrypted data to " + encryptionFile.toURI().toURL().toString()
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Presumably you have to decrypt the key element first (using the RSA private key) - and then decrypt the data element using the key just obtained using the symmetrical algorithm specified (3DES). Also it seems that the CipherValues need to be base-64 decoded to bytes.

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks for the reply. I have found SAP blog [link](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/12/24/how-to-encryptdecrypt-xml-payload-with-aes256-cbc-and-rsa-algorithm-in-sap-cpi/) describing what you mention and with difference on encrypted data as AES while 3DES. However, I am encountering this error java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key size. Please help me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check `decryptedKey.length` and it should be 24 bytes. If not your encryption is wrong.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I manage to get the right key by adding the DESedeKeySpec.
` DESedeKeySpec desEdeKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(decryptedKey);
  SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
  SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(desEdeKeySpec);`

Now I no longer have any errors on compile and runtime but I am just getting back my input as the output. so I'm I am not sure now what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: I have added `Document decryptedDoc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptedData.getBytes("UTF-8")));` to get result xml document but I'm encountering `[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.`

Comment: but when I enclose the decrypted string in I suppose root element `String newDecryptedData = "<root>"+decryptedData+"</root>"; Document decryptedDoc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(newDecryptedData.getBytes("UTF-8")));` the error changes to `[Fatal Error] :1:11: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1d) was found in the element content of the document.`. Please help point out what I need to fix and what could probably doing wrong the entire program.