# XML Decryption with Apache Santuario - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, xml, encryption

Need to decrypt response XML payload but I encountered ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error as in the title. This is the same requirement I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77472096/steps-on-how-to-decrypt-xml-using-private-key-in-a-pfx-keystore-with-java) but for this one I use Apache Santuario library as described in the samples on these sites [DevX](https://www.devx.com/xml-zone/28701/) and [google git](https://apache.googlesource.com/santuario-java/+/9155bb454492745edfecc681b0708fe34dc3d511/samples/org/apache/xml/security/samples/encryption/Decrypter.java). The difference against those samples is that the Private key inside a PFX file (which also has the certificates) will used for decryption to the best of my understanding.

Please help point out what I could be doing wrong.

This is what I have so far

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class JM_XMLDecryption_local {

    static org.slf4j.Logger log =
        org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(
                JM_XMLDecryption_local.class.getName());
    static {
        org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
    }

    public static void main(String unused[]) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "response.xml";
        File encryptionFile = new File(fileName);
        //create document from file
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(encryptionFile);
        System.out.println("Encryption document loaded from " + encryptionFile.toURI().toURL().toString());
        NodeList cipherValueNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("xenc:CipherValue");
        //get encrypted key and data
        Element encKey = null;
        Element encData = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < cipherValueNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                encKey = (Element)cipherValueNodes.item(i);
            }
            else {
                encData = (Element)cipherValueNodes.item(i);
            }
        }

        //load private key from PFX file
        String keyStorePW = "PFX password";
        String keyStore = "PFX FILE";
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(keyStore), keyStorePW.toCharArray());
        String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, keyStorePW.toCharArray());
        //decrypt encrypted key with private key
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
        byte[] encryptedKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encKey.getTextContent());
        byte[] decryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(encryptedKeyBytes);
        //generate secret key
        DESedeKeySpec desEdeKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(decryptedKey);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(desEdeKeySpec);
        //decrypt the encrypted data
        XMLCipher xmlCipher = XMLCipher.getInstance();
        xmlCipher.init(XMLCipher.DECRYPT_MODE, null);
        xmlCipher.setKEK(key);
        xmlCipher.doFinal(document, encData);
        //writed decrypted XML file
        File outputFile = new File("decryptedInfo.xml");
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(f);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        f.close();
        System.out.println(
            "Wrote document containing decrypted data to " + outputFile.toURI().toURL().toString()
        );
    }
}
```

Error Message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:739)
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:482)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.item(DeepNodeListImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher$Factory.newEncryptedData(XMLCipher.java:2223)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptToByteArray(XMLCipher.java:1736)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptElement(XMLCipher.java:1673)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.doFinal(XMLCipher.java:945)
    at JM_XMLDecryption_local.main(JM_XMLDecryption_local.java:76)
```